# Using the definition of Θ prove or disprove the following:

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

$$
\dfrac{4n^4 -18n^3 +3n^2 -660}{n^2 +560n -1024} = Θ(n^2)
$$

It's been quite a while since I've one this as a ratio and I'm a bit lost on what steps to take for this. I know we'll need to prove both big O and big Omega but simplifying the ratio has me stuck.

Answer (score 1):

This ratio can be rewritten as $f(n)=n^2g(1/n)/h(1/n)$ where $g(x)=4-18x+3x^2-660x^3$ and $h(x)=1+560x-1024x^2$. Hence $g(x)\to4$ and $h(x)\to1$ when $x\to0$, which implies that $g(1/n)/h(1/n)\to4$ when $n\to\infty$. Pick some $N$ such that $|g(1/n)/h(1/n)-4|\leqslant1$ for every $n\geqslant N$, then $3n^2\leqslant f(n)\leqslant5n^2$ for every $n\geqslant N$, in particular $f(n)=\Theta(n^2)$.

**Quantitatively:** If $|x|\leqslant\frac1{10,000}$, $3\leqslant g(x)\leqslant5$ and $\frac12\leqslant h(x)\leqslant\frac32$ hence, for every $n\geqslant10,000$, $2n^2\leqslant f(n)\leqslant10n^2$.

Comment: I've never seen this technique before. I really can't make heads or tails of it.

Comment: Cool. (1) Is there a logical implication from the first part of your comment to the second part? (2) Which technique(s) have you seen before?

Comment: In class we would prove something is Θ in two parts. We would first solve for Big-O then Solve for big-Omega. IN the first part we start by taking the LHS of the equation (the f(n)) making it larger and then eliminating the n terms to find the k value that g(n) (in this case n^2) needs to be multiplied by and it would also imply a n value where that holds true for all values of n greater than that. In the second part we do the same thing but instead we make LHS value smaller to find the proper k value.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Divide it out to get

$$f(n)=\frac{4n^4-18n^3+3n^2-660}{n^2+560n-1024}=4n^2+an+b+\frac{cn+d}{n^2+560n-1024}$$

for some $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R$. Show that

$$\left\vert an+b+\frac{cn+d}{n^2+560n-1024}\right\vert\le n^2$$

for sufficiently large $n$ and conclude that $n^2\le f(n)$ and $f(n)\le 5n^2$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this as In class we would first prove big-O then prove big-Omega in two seperate steps. in order to find the k value that would be used for the big-O side we would set an inequality and find that: $$4n^4-18n^3+3n^2-660/n^2+560n-1024 <= 4n^4+18n^4+3n^4+660n^4/n^2+560n-1024$$ I don't think I've ever seen what you're suggesting.

Comment: @Frank: That’s exactly what I’m suggesting: showing that $n^2\le f(n)$ for sufficiently large $n$ is showing that $n^2$ is $O\big(f(n)\big)$, and showing that $f(n)\le 5n^2$ for sufficiently large $n$ is showing that $f(n)$ is $O(n^2)$. When you’ve done both of those, you can legitimately conclude that $f(n)$ is $\Theta(n^2)$.

Comment: I'm sorry I just don't understand the way you've shown it here. I'll have to speak with someone about it on Monday. Thanks for the attempt.

Comment: @Frank: Looking again at your previous comment, I think that you have a serious misunderstanding of the big-$O$ notation: that inequality has absolutely nothing to do with the problem at hand. Perhaps you could state exactly what definition of big-$O$ you’re using.

Comment: Perhaps If i knew where you're going with you're hint I might be able to better understand. I'm not sure what you're even "dividing out" how did you get the RHS of that first equation?

Comment: @Frank: Your function of $n$ is a quotient of two polynomials; I simply performed ordinary polynomial long division to get a quotient and a remainder, except that I didn’t actually complete the computation to find $a,b,c$, and $d$. The function $4n^2+an+b+\frac{cn+d}{n^2+560n-1024}$ is your original quotient, simply expressed in a more convenient form that makes it clear that its dominant term is $4n^2$. The rest of the hint just provides some of the details of the standard way to show that $f(n)$ (your function of $n$) and $n^2$ are big-$O$ of each other.